# why 2/2 checks are failing to 1/2 in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I launched an instance from a Public AMI (`Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-085925f297f89fce1 (64-bit x86) / ami-05d7ab19b28efa213 (64-bit Arm)`) and found that I could not ssh into the instance. I received the error `Connection timed out.`

I checked the security groups to verify that Port 22 was associated with `0.0.0.0/0`. Additionally, I checked the route tables to verify that `0.0.0.0/0` is associated with target gateway attached to the VPC.

I find that only `1/2 status checks` have passed - the instance status check failed. It's working fine when I have tried rebooting the instance but I need to figure out why this is happening for every two days.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying that the status check starts off with 2/2, but later changes to 1/2? And the instance is fine after rebooting, but fails after a while? Which Instance Type is it using?

Comment: yes @JohnRotenstein, I'm using t3.2xlarge with 500 GB of volume. 
I'm getting this warning alerts from Zabbix
"OK: nvme0n1: Disk read/write request responses are too high (read > 20 ms for 15m or write > 20 ms for 15m)"

Comment: What are you running on the instance?

Comment: we are running influexdb on it. I hope we don't have any option to use RDS for it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 status checks performed against an EC2:

- System status checks - These checks are against the underlying physical host, such as a power failure or network failure.
- Instance status checks - These checks are against the VM itself, with issues such as a corrupted file system or failure with the virtual networking.

You can find out more information about the reasons for failure of status checks [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html).

It is possible to add autorecovery to the instance if it fails a system check, more steps can be found in [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/automatic-recovery-ec2-cloudwatch/).

There will be individual metrics regarding which of these status checks failed within CloudWatch. The normal solution to resolve this is to stop and instance and then start it again. By doing this hard reboot you will had the instance migrate to another physical host (within the same subnet and AZ).

Answer (score 0):

**Restart** server instance, solution for fix this issue.

- In that point server **public IP** not change.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used the same IP in multiple security groups of a single EC2, causing the security check to fail